# How can I draw epicycloid in java?

Tags: java, math, graphics, awt

I have such parametric equations:

[image: parametric equations]

and I need to draw epicycloid. How can I do this with awt? (or maybe I should use other technologies)

Comment: The duplink gives some references on drawing curves using AWT.  You should be able to read them and then apply the knowledge to your specific problem.

Comment: @StephenC duplink?

Comment: Yes.  Raise your eyes to the top of this page.   "This question already has answers here: <duplicate question>".